# What is the license for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server?

Tags: server, lts, license

What is the license for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server?

When I check the download site I don't see the license there or on the documentation page.  Can someone please let me know what it is licensed under?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "License"?  (We need some more specific information to determine what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (Desktop/Server/etc.) **itself** isn't under a license.

Rather, it's components and underlying / included software, drivers, etc. are under various licenses, such as [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html).

However, you are free to modify / use it to fulfill whatever purpose you desire, even for commercial purposes.

Please see [Licensing](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing).